# How to use lists in conditionals

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x, python-3.4

I asked a question a couple of hours ago, but it got closed as a duplicate. I was asking if I could use the index of lists to validate answers. This was my original code:

```
message = input("Problem: ")
for item in keyword_list:
    if item in message:
        if item == "screen" or item == "cracked" or item == "blank":
            subp.call("screen.txt", shell=True)
```

...and keyword_list: `keyword_list = ["screen", "cracked", "blank"]` etc....

I got told (as an answer to the question) to do this instead:

```
message = input("Problem: ")
for item in keyword_list:
    if item in message:
        if item in keyword_list[:3]:
            subp.call("screen.txt", shell=True)
```

It does not work now: the opening of the text file does not work, it doesn't open, just skips it out, and if you input a keyword with index of more than 0, then it does not do anything.

Can someone tell me what's happening. There is a screen.txt in the right directory btw.

Thanks :))

Comment: "but it got closed as a duplicate" If this is the same question, people are going to close it again. Is this a different question?

Comment: show us your full script, how many indexes are in keyword_list?

Comment: This isn't the same question, this is an error i got by following their advice

Comment: If the opening of the file doesn't work, show the code for the opening of the file. Also I'm not sure what `subp.call("screen.txt")` is supposed to do? is `screen.txt` against all odds an executable?

Comment: There are 12 indexes. I do not have access to the code right now because I am in a lesson, sorry.

Comment: Screen.txt is the file I want to open. T

Comment: *I named the subprocess module subp for ease.

Comment: `subp.call` is not how you open files. Use `open` (and be sure to read the documentation of it). I would recommend to read through a python tutorial, e.g. [the official one](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/).

Comment: so, at input, what are you entering, and is what you are entering within your first four indexes of keyword-list?

Comment: I want to open the file in the default program, not in python.

Comment: What I am inputting is what a user might input as a problem with their phone. E.g. My phone screen has cracked. The program would then recognise screen and cracked (the keywords) and take them to a solution in a text file (hence screen.txt)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import subprocess as subp

k = ['screen','cracked','blank']
m = input('Problem:')
for i in k:
    if i in m:
        file = r'C:\somedir\somefile.txt'
        subp.Popen (file, shell=True)
```

That will work, if your list `k` is reasonably small. If your list with keywords is large, then you could do the comparison the other way around by splitting the input message `m`

```
import subprocess as subp

k = ['screen','cracked','blank']
m = input('Problem:')
for i in m.split():
    if i in k:
        file = r'C:\somedir\somefile.txt'
        subp.Popen (file, shell=True)
```

HTH